# Delete all pages from domains from browser history

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'd like to remove all history pertaining to certain domains from Google Chrome's history. I *don't* want to delete everything else; deleting entire days isn't a viable solution, and neither is manually selecting every page from these domains over the last 7 months of browser history.

[This thread](http://iwastesomuchtime.com/on/?i=37416) suggests a few ways (opening the browser history file, manually editing, or using some form of SQL client) - these seem rather hackish. Is there an easy, in-browser method of doing this or, failing that, an extension which enables said functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [History 2](https://sites.google.com/site/history2chrome/) extension is able to do what you are looking for.

Comment: It does, but its incredibly slow and doesn't seem to delete all entries from history.